# Federated query to VIEW in Athena: mismatched input 'from'

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-athena

I have a SQL query that I am trying to build a `VIEW` from, for AWS Athena.
The Select statement works, however when I add the CREATE statement, it starts to error.

```
line 12:1: 
mismatched input 'from' expecting {<eof>, 'where', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'lateral', 'window', 'union', 'except', 'intersect', 'sort', 'cluster', 'distribute'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 7740824a-5db1-4409-87bb-d70ab321734a; proxy: null)
```

The only change that I have made so far is to change the FROM inside the left join to `FROM "sentryx"."public"."vw_last_create_dates"`

I need troubleshooting help to find out why that error is occuring

- Does Athena allow a federated query to build a view ?
- I have checked the braces in the entire query
- the internal select statement works

````sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW heatmap_backflow_alert_90days AS
SELECT  devicealerthistoryid 
       ,deviceid 
       ,latitude 
       ,longitude 
       ,alertcounter 
       ,alertsetdatetime 
       ,last_modify_date 
       ,AlertKey 
       ,sitename
FROM 
(
    SELECT  devicealerthistoryid 
           ,d.deviceid 
           ,latitude 
           ,longitude 
           ,alertcounter 
           ,alertsetdatetime 
           ,COALESCE(datelastmodified,datecreated) last_modify_date 
           ,"concat"("lower"("replace"(cd.database,'ArkNET_')),'*',CAST(productalerttypeid AS varchar(12)),'*',CAST(d.deviceid AS varchar(12)),'*me') AlertKey 
           ,"lower"("replace"(cd.database,'ArkNET_')) sitename 
           ,"row_number"() OVER (PARTITION BY da.devicealerthistoryid,da.database ORDER BY datelastmodified DESC) row_num
    FROM 
    (((metrology_consumption_base_db.devicealerthistory da
        INNER JOIN metrology_consumption_base_db.device d
        ON (da.productid = d.deviceid))
        INNER JOIN metrology_consumption_base_db.customerdevice cd
        ON (cd.deviceid = d.deviceid))
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  SITENAME 
                   ,"max"(last_create_date) last_create_date
            FROM "sentryx"."public"."vw_last_create_dates"
            WHERE ("alert_type" = 'backflow') 
            GROUP BY  SITENAME 
        ) T4
        ON ("lower"("replace"(cd.database, 'ArkNET_')) = T4.SITENAME)
    )
    WHERE ((((productalerttypeid = 10) AND (alertcleardatetime IS NULL)) AND (COALESCE(T4.SITENAME, cd.database) IS NOT NULL)) AND (COALESCE(datelastmodified, datecreated) > COALESCE(last_create_date, "date_parse"('2019-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))))  
) T5
WHERE (row_num = 1) ; ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limitations for Views**
Athena view names cannot contain special characters, other than underscore (_). For more information, see Names for Tables, Databases, and Columns.

Avoid using reserved keywords for naming views. If you use reserved keywords, use double quotes to enclose reserved keywords in your queries on views. See Reserved Keywords.

-- **You cannot use views with federated data sources, external Hive metastores, or
UDFs.**

You cannot use views with geospatial functions.

You cannot use views to manage access control on data in Amazon S3. To query a view, you need permissions to access the data stored in Amazon S3. For more information, see Access to Amazon S3.